# Ubuntu 22.04.02: wired ethernet e1000e stops working after resuming from suspend

Tags: networking, 22.04, suspend

Recently installed a wired ethernet to a long running Ubuntu 22.04.02 system, and the ethernet network fails to reconnect after resuming from suspend. The wifi works fine, it's only the wired ethernet that fails. No problems after a reboot, until I suspend the next time.

It's using the `e1000e` driver. lspci shows

```
0000:00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (17) I219-LM (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (17) I219-LM
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

and `lshw -C Network` shows:

```
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (17) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 11
       serial: 08:92:04:e0:5b:05
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.19.0-46-generic duplex=full firmware=2.3-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:218 memory:75180000-7519ffff
```

removing and reloading the e1000e kernel module doesn't help, nor does restarting the NetworkManager service.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205015 Possibly related. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: don't think that this is related, as there are no error messages in the logs, and it's 100% reproducible with the first suspend after a reboot.